# JMSWMQ00018: failed to connect to queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm getting the error while ant script is trying to put a message in mq queue. I provided the correct queue manager details in the property file. 
The same qm I'm able to connect from rfhutil, and able to write the message to the queue

Comment: You'd probably have to provide some code details for anyone to be able to help you out here.  What Java program is invoked from the Ant script?  If you wrote it, share some of the Java code snippets.  Maybe also show how properties are passed to that Java from the Ant script and/or property file which you seem to be suggesting are relevant here.

Comment: You will need to provide much more detail to get anything other than a guess at what the cause of the problem may be.  with IBM MQ JMS exceptions they are fairly generic, the one you posted just means JMS could not connect to the queue manager "for some reason".  To get the reason you would need to provide the underlying Linked MQ exception which is more granular, and in some cases you would also need to see what the queue manager's own error log shows.  Provide your code that connect to MQ and provide the full stack from the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information and you should be posting your code where it is failing.

Also, a JMS exception does not provide enough information.  You need to get the MQ reason code.  Update your code as follows:

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

The LinkedException will contain the MQ reason code.